# Python pandas pivot output differs from documentation -- resulting DataFrame has column name in top left

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Here's an excerpt from the pandas pivot docs:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one','one','one','two','two','two'],
                       'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                       'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
>>> df
    foo   bar  baz
0   one   A    1
1   one   B    2
2   one   C    3
3   two   A    4
4   two   B    5
5   two   C    6
>>> df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')
     A   B   C
one  1   2   3
two  4   5   6
```

When I run the exact code above (pandas 0.19.2), I instead get the following output:

```
bar  A  B  C
foo         
one  1  2  3
two  4  5  6
```

My questions are:

- Do other people get this behaviour?
- Why does the behaviour differ from the documentation?
- What actually is the nature of this resulting DataFrame? I am quite new to pandas so this is probably a stupid question. But I don't think I've seen a name (bar) over the index before. I can't work out what it is?

Thanks.

Comment: it's naming the index `'foo'` , this probably didn't happen for the version of pandas that ran that code

Comment: I ran `df.index.name` and received `None`. Doesn't that contradict that? Also, this is a mistake in the docs, right? It's the same version, they should be showing the correct output.

Comment: The generated docs are not necessarily generated by the same version, also see my answer that shows that the index now has a name, my pandas version is 0.19.2

Comment: I must have made a mistake, I receive the index name now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to an older version of pandas that generated the docs, in the latest versions it will name the index if passed, in this case `'foo'`

```
In [111]:
pv = df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')
pv.index

Out[111]:
Index(['one', 'two'], dtype='object', name='foo')
```

You can see that the index now has a `'name'` attribute